# Namespace not found when adding custom dll packed via NuSpec to ASP.NET Core project

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, nuget, .net-core

I have a brand-new asp.net core web api project targeting .net framework 4.6. For business reasons, we need to access an old .net 3.5 library. I ran

```
nuget spec old-library.dll
```

then

```
nuget pack old-library.dll.
```

and installed the package. However, I can't seem to access the library.

```
using old-library-namespace;
```

just doesn't resolve. I know we should be able to use existing .net libraries, and it seems like other people have tried this, but I am at a loss as to the next step here.

Comment: does `dotnet restore` show any errors? Where is the library placed in the nuget package (rename to .zip > extract)? it should be `lib/net35` (though a newer net* is okay as well)

Comment: No errors on the restore, though it is just creating a folder called old-library.dll.1.0.0 in the root of my project. In package (viewed in NuGet Package  Explorer) everything is in the base - no folders at all.

Comment: Not sure if it is the same case... but I had a similar issue like that and I discovered I could not add cross framework versions. my solution was to disassemble (ildasm), sign, and recompile. It's kind of a bit hammer, but that work on my case...

Comment: Oh btw... my case was not using dot-net core, just different .net framework versions. From core I've discovered that not all .net libraries are available for core since core is just a subset of the main .net framework.

Comment: @Feasoron to clarify: you are using ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework (not .NET Core)? That's how I interpreted your "targeting 4.6" statement.

Comment: Yes. ASP.NET Core on the .NET framework. Sorry, their naming makes it very easy to mix up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.nuspec` file for the dll, make sure that the `<files>` section sets the target path of the dll file correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <!-- your metadata -->
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <!-- and framework assemblies you reference -->
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Xml" targetFramework="net35" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="old-library.dll" target="lib\net35" />
  </files>
</package>
```